# trying to output my lists in columns and rows. the first call outputs the right amount of rows, but the second call does a few too many

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Im Tryng to output my code in columns and rows, and for the first call with only two rows necessary, it does fine, but for the later call, there are too many rows, even with the limiting while loop. the while loop uses a code per line * row nubmer to limit the number of possible rows, but even with the conditional operator limiting the rows (I want twelve), it outputs a couple too many

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void loadArray(int userArray[],
  const int userArraySize);
void printArray(const int userArray[],
  const int userArraySize, int columnElements = 24,
    ostream & output = cout);
int main() {
  int smallArray[12], bigArray[100];

  printBanner();
  while (true) {
    loadArray(smallArray, 12);
    cout << "\n  ";
    printArray(smallArray, 12);
    loadArray(bigArray, 100);
    system("pause");
    cout << "\n  ";
    printArray(bigArray, 100, 38);
    connectFile();

  }

}

void printArray(const int userArray[],
  const int userArraySize, int columnElements, ostream &
    output) {
  int rows = 0, elementCounter = 0, extraElementCounter = 0, elementPerRow = 0;
  (userArraySize > 12 ? extraElementCounter = 20 : extraElementCounter = 10);
  (userArraySize > 12 ? rows = 12 : rows = 2);
  while (elementCounter < (columnElements * (rows))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < userArraySize; i++) {
      cout << userArray[i];
      ((elementPerRow + 1) % 5 == 0 ? cout << "   " : cout << "");
      elementCounter++;
      elementPerRow++;
      (elementCounter % columnElements == 0 || elementCounter == 0 ? cout << "\n  " :
        cout << "");
      (elementCounter % columnElements == 0 ? elementPerRow = 0 : elementPerRow =
        elementPerRow);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < extraElementCounter; i++) {
    cout << userArray[i];
    ((elementPerRow + 1) % 5 == 0 ? cout << "   " : cout << "");
    elementPerRow++;
  }

}
void loadArray(int userArray[],
  const int userArraySize) {
  unsigned seed = time(0);
  srand(seed);

  userArray[userArraySize];
  for (int i = 0; i < userArraySize; i++) {
    userArray[i] = (rand() % (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: The inner loop in `printArray` prints all the elements, before the condition in the outer loop is checked a second time. By the time it's checked, it's already too late. You probably meant to combine the two conditions: `for (int i = 0; i < userArraySize && elementCounter < columnElements * rows; i++) {...}`